# Summaries within Tensorflow Estimator API - More clarity needed

Tags: tensorflow

Could someone help me on  creating tensor board summaries for loss, accuracy using Estimator API. I created `tf.summary.scalar('loss',loss)` and `tf.summary.scalar('accuracy',accuracy)` in my model_func. However, I am seeing only the `global_step` summary in my tensor board. Could some body point me to a relevant example that explains summary writer and logging hooks well using estimator API

Answer (score 1):

1) Create your summaries in your `model_fn`
2) Merge them with `tf.summary.merge_all`
3) Pass the merged summary to a `tf.train.SummarySaverHook`
4) Pass this hook to the `training_hooks` param *(As a `List`)* of the `EstimatorSpec` that you return with the your `model_fn`

*Note: The summaries defined in the `model_fn` cannot be passed outside the scpoe of the function. Hence, you cannot use the `hooks` param of the `estimator.train` method to pass in your hooks.*

Answer (score 0):

You need to hook those summaries with estimator. Something like this:

```
  # tensors_to_log can be either a list or a dictionary.
  tensors_to_log = ['loss', 'accuracy']
  logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(tensors=tensors_to_log, every_n_iter=100)
  xx_estimator.train(input_fn,steps, hooks=[logging_hook])
```

A more complete example can be found in this [tensorflow mnist example](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/5ddd7e55c9ab6ae10a1459afc6309a2a417398d9/official/mnist/mnist.py#L211).